# Using SQL queries to act as search options in a power BI report

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Not too brushed up on SQL within Power BI. I am trying to create a Power BI dashboard with the ability to use pre-written SQL statements/queries/files as search options (in the form of a search menu preferably) for the data tables I have already loaded onto the PowerBI report. Not quite sure on how to do this as I wont be using an SQL server and will just be using the SQL scripts. Perhaps connected to some splicers/buttons?

Any help would be much apprecieted :)

I tried using the blank query on the "get data" option to copy my sql scripts into there but no success. I have also tried adapting queries for the csv table files themselves.

[image]